# non executable folder

Tags: file, ubuntu

How to make map/folder/dir not executable like I want to have images folder and there I want to say in ubuntu folder/home/images/ is only for photos like jpg,jpeg,png,gif and if for any reson someone upload some script like script.php can NOT fire that script!

So make folder where no script can be fired (executed) in ubuntu?
I think it has to be something with permissions 666 or 644, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: On linux, the individual files determine whether they can be executed or not, not folders - so you can't make a folder whose files placed  in that folder cannot be executed. You can also disable file execution on entire file systems, but not on files in individual folders within a file system. Then again, you could be talking about files served via a web server - which is something entierley different.

Answer (score 0):

well, a php file isn't executed (it's read by the php-module) so you're not save disabling the x-bit.

You must filter the uploads on file-suffix.

Comment: Iḿ doing that but, what is someone hack it and upload some script what then?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your web server not to run scripts from the upload directories.